How to use Stripe import extension?
https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/stripeimport
The extension doesnt provide any use cases or detailed information on how to use this. Can someone give an idea on how to use this please? Thanks

The extension is used to import Subscriptions, Customer, Charges etc from Stripe to CiviCRM

Like it can import Subscriptions, Customer, Charges etc from Stripe to CiviCRM which was created in one site to another site? I cant find any information in the document.
